# Latex: Figure positioned out of order

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have the following latex code:

```
% Preamble
% ---
\documentclass{article}

% Packages
% ---
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \title{Electronics Equations}
    \author{Tyler Hilbert}
    \date{}
    \maketitle

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=50mm]{FormulaWheel.png}
    \end{figure}

    Ohm's Law: V = I*R

    \bigskip

    Current: I = dQ/dt

    Voltage: V = dw/dQ

    Power: p = dw/dt

\end{document}
```

When I compile and create a pdf I get the following result:
[image]
What I am wondering is why is the figure after all the equations?  I put the figure in before the equations because I wanted it at the beginning.  How can I make it at the top of the document where it is relative to the other elements like in the ordering in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `figure` environment, which is a float environment. The idea is to let latex figure out its optimal place. If you do not want that, than just use `\includegraphics[width=50mm]{FormulaWheel.png}` directly (just delete the `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` lines).

You can find more details about floats [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions).